# Moving the label in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, label, mouselistener

I wanted to make a label and move it on the screen. I tried to find some videos and other sources to find how to do so but couldn't understand them well, or they used things I never heard of.
So I made this code (the frame is extending JFrame and implementing MouseListener):

This is the main Class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

And this is the class with the code:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements MouseListener{

    JLabel label;

    Frame() {
        label = new JLabel();

        label.setBounds(800, 200, 200, 200);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.addMouseListener(this);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1200, 700);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(label);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Point x = e.getPoint();
        label.setLocation(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

When I try to move the label, the label moves, but not in the place I want it to.
Only sometimes, the label moves in the direction I want to, but most of the time, it moves in any random direction. Even if I just click, it moves.
However, even if the label moves in the direction I want to, it goes to a random length in the direction.

Comment: Please provide [mre]

Comment: 1) Agree with @c0der on the MRE. 2) But I feel this entire approach is less than optimal. Instead of a `null` layout and moving components about, I'd custom paint the panel and use a basic string to replace the label. The use of `getLocationOnScreen` also seems error-prone. I'd always use the location within the component of interest. 3) *"I tried to find some videos and other sources"* Forget the videos, as to the 'other sources', I'd highly recommend the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/index.html) & the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: You need to use `getPoint`. It won't be at random, if you print the coordinates, you will know it would be right. You will also know that where you would like it to move to and based on that you can change your logic.

Comment: @c0der I just made a class named Frame extending JFrame and implementing MouseListener, a label named label which I want to drag. And all the code is within the question only, just that the main method is in another class and label is available to the whole Frame class

Comment: @HiteshA.Bosamiya I just it and after printing the points I got, I found that e.getPoint, according to me returns the correct place of the cursor but the label is not going to that exact place

Comment: @HiteshA.Bosamiya I just tried it once again. The label was on mid-right but when I clicked it, (didn't drag at all) it went to top-left. And the point that was returned was of the place the label got moved to

Comment: _I just made a class named Frame extending JFrame and implementing MouseListener_ please provide mre

Comment: *"I just made a class.."* So post that short (complete) code as a [mre]. Your statement reads here like *"to help me, you just need to .."* which is where I stop reading, because we don't *need* to do anything. Our interest is purely academic, and there are plenty of others around here who *do* follow our advice and make it *easy* for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using a `MouseListener` to  track when the mouse is pressed and get the coordinates of the label, alongside a `MouseMotionAdapter` to track when the mouse is moved (or dragged) to help you set the new location of the label.

**Update:**
To add more info on how this works, `e.getLocationOnScreen().x` returns the X coordinate of the mouse pressed based on the computer screen, while `label.getX()` returns the X coordinate of the label based on the Java Swing container it has been added to; in this case, that is the `JFrame`. So, one has to subtract that value from the previous one to get the actual X coordinate of the label on the screen. Same applies for the Y coordinate. Once you have both coordinates, you can use the `label.setLocation()` method to change the location of the label, and hence, move the label around the screen.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class LabelDragExample extends JFrame {
    JLabel label;
    int x, y;

    public LabelDragExample() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(800, 200, 200, 200);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - label.getX();
                y = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - label.getY();
            }
        });
        label.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                label.setLocation(e.getLocationOnScreen().x - x, e.getLocationOnScreen().y - y);
                x = e.getLocationOnScreen().x - label.getX();
                y = e.getLocationOnScreen().y - label.getY();

            }
        });
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1200, 700);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(label);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new LabelDragExample();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work now. But what was the thing in the code I made that made the label move even on just clicking and making it move so randomly

Comment: Yea. I used the mouseReleased method so it means it would get invoked only when I release the button, and in the meantime, the label would not move at all. I was asking if you could tell why the wrong cords were being given to the label if you could

Comment: @YashwardhanBisht, in this approach the label is moved along the mouse pointer through `mouseDragged` event hence you don't see the actual problem you faced as here the difference of mouse's current position w.r.t. original position is added to label's current position `[x = mLOS.orig.x - label.x; mLOS.new.x - x = mLOS.new.x - (mLOS.orig.x - label.x) = mLOS.new.x - mLOS.orig.x + label.x = diff + label.x]` Please refer to my reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/70727525/12944233, which shows the correct approach to align label with the mouse pointer when the mouse button is release.

Answer (score -1):

I observed that there is some offset between mouse's (0, 0) position on container and label's (0, 0) position. In the attached code, I am setting the mouse pointer to the label's on screen position point but you will notice that it does not get exactly aligned with label's (0, 0) position. We need to adjust for this offset. Once we adjust for the offset things will be fine. You can try out the attached code:

```
package com.example.temp;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    JLabel label;
    Point offset = new Point();

    Main() {
        addMouseListener(this);

        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(1200, 700);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.add(label);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            Point labelOSPoint = label.getLocationOnScreen();
            robot.mouseMove(labelOSPoint.x, labelOSPoint.y);
        } catch (AWTException ignored) {
        }
        Point labelPoint = label.getLocationOnScreen();
        Point containerPoint = this.getLocationOnScreen();
        offset.x = labelPoint.x - containerPoint.x;
        offset.y = labelPoint.y - containerPoint.y;
        System.out.println("offset x = " + offset.x + ", y = " + offset.y);
        label.setText("Location: x = " + label.getX() + ", y = " + label.getY());
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        Point mousePoint = e.getPoint();
        System.out.println("mousePoint x = " + mousePoint.x + ", y = " + mousePoint.y);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        Point mousePoint = e.getPoint();
        label.setLocation(mousePoint.x - offset.x, mousePoint.y - offset.y);
        label.setText("Location: x = " + label.getX() + ", y = " + label.getY());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
}
```