# Problem with disappering object on JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with my program. The rectangle disappears in a certain area on the frame and I have no idea why. I wrote a similar program lately and it worked just fine. The difference was that I draw a circle, not a rectangle.

Could you please help me find the problem?

```
public class Runner {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppFrame app = new AppFrame();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Drawing extends JPanel{
    
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
    }

    public void repaintObject() {
        repaint();
    }}
```

---

```
public class AppFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    private int height =600;
    private int width = 600;
    
    private JButton upButton;
    private JButton downButton;
    private JButton rightButton;
    private JButton leftButton;
    
    private JPanel drawingPanel;
    private JPanel buttonsPanel;
    
    private Drawing object;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    public AppFrame() {
        
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        
        drawingPanel= new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel= new JPanel();
        
        drawingPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        upButton = new JButton("Up");
        downButton = new JButton("Down");
        rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        
        buttonsPanel.add(upButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        buttonsPanel.add(downButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        buttonsPanel.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        buttonsPanel.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        
        x=100;
        y=100;
        
        object = new Drawing();
        object.setX(x);
        object.setY(y);
        drawingPanel.add(object);
        
        this.add(drawingPanel);
        this.add(buttonsPanel);
        
        upButton.addActionListener(this);
        downButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightButton.addActionListener(this);
        leftButton.addActionListener(this);
    
        this.setSize(height, width);
        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        
        System.out.println(x+"    "+ y);
        if(source == upButton) {
        
            if(y>=50) {
                y = y - 50;
                object.setY(y);
                object.repaintObject();
            }
            
        } else if(source == downButton) {
            if(y<350) {
                y = y+50;
                object.setY(y);
                object.repaintObject();
            }
        } else if(source == rightButton) {
            if(x<550) {
                x = x+50;
                object.setX(x);
                object.repaintObject();
            }
            
        } else if(source == leftButton) {
            if(x>=50) {
                x=x-50;
                object.setX(x);
                object.repaintObject();
            }
        }   }}
```

Comment: Don't use the x/y variables and override getXY() and getY(). Those are methods of the Container class. If you need to track the location of the rectangle, then use different variable and method names. Also, don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent(). See: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for more information and example on how to make your painting more flexible.

Comment: i changed the code like you advised but i still get the same result with dissappearing object.                        
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  Object source = e.getSource();
  
  if(source == upButton) {
  
   if(object.y>=50) {
    object.y = object.y - 50;
    object.repaint();
   }
   
  } ..... 
  }                                                          public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
  g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
 }

Comment: *"i changed the code l"* Code in comments is unreadable (to me at least). Please [edit] the question to show the changes where people will notice them & can easily read the code.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) sections.

Comment: BTW instead of overriding `paint()` it is (most often) recommended to override `paintComponent()` (eventually `paintBorder()` or `paintChildren()`, if appropriate); BTW2 please use the `@Override` annotation if overriding a method (helps who ever is reading the code, and enables the compiler to check if the override is correct)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the rectangle at different positions by overriding `paint()`, you can use a `JLabel`/`JPanel` to draw the rectangle (or whatever shape you wish, as long as you ovveride the `paintComponent()`), and then use `setLocation()` of that component to change its location (according to the speed you want the rectangle to move with). To avoid having the rectangle escaping the boundaries of the main panel, you can perform some checks using the current postiion of the rectangle, rectangle's dimensions, as well as main panel's dimensions. Thus, whatever size you give to the rectangle, or the panel/frame intially, or resizing the frame window while the program is running, the rectangle will still be able to move within the boundaries of its parent component. Below is a working example. If you would like to move the rectangle around using the mouse, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70719672/17865804).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class App extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JLabel label;
    private JButton upButton;
    private JButton downButton;
    private JButton rightButton;
    private JButton leftButton;
    JPanel p; // main panel
    int rectHeight = 40;
    int rectWidth = 40;
    int speed = 50;

    public App() {
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setBounds(10, 10, rectWidth, rectHeight);
        label.setBackground(Color.RED);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(null);
        p.add(label);

        upButton = new JButton("Up");
        downButton = new JButton("Down");
        rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        buttonsPanel.add(upButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        buttonsPanel.add(downButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        buttonsPanel.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        buttonsPanel.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        upButton.addActionListener(this);
        downButton.addActionListener(this);
        rightButton.addActionListener(this);
        leftButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        int xPos = (int) label.getLocation().getX();
        int yPos = (int) label.getLocation().getY();
        int pHeight = (int) p.getSize().getHeight();
        int pWidth = (int) p.getSize().getWidth();

        if (source == upButton) {
            if (yPos - speed > 0)
                label.setLocation(xPos, yPos - speed);
            else
                label.setLocation(xPos, 0);

        } else if (source == downButton) {
            if (yPos + speed < pHeight - rectHeight)
                label.setLocation(xPos, yPos + speed);
            else
                label.setLocation(xPos, pHeight - rectHeight);

        } else if (source == leftButton) {
            if (xPos - speed > 0)
                label.setLocation(xPos - speed, yPos);
            else
                label.setLocation(0, yPos);

        } else if (source == rightButton) {
            if (xPos + speed < pWidth - rectWidth)
                label.setLocation(xPos + speed, yPos);
            else
                label.setLocation(pWidth - rectWidth, yPos);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }
}
```